# Run command in powercli using batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, powercli

I am planning to use batch file to run few commands in VMWare PowerCli tool. I am able to open Powercli tool by batch file. But after the tool is opened, it should automatically go to a specific folder and then run a file from that folder.

Eventually I would like this to add in Task scheduler so that it runs on specific time with no human interaction.

Is there a way to do it in batch or cmd? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any reason why you don't simply stick with powershell?

Answer (score 0):

If I have read the question correctly you want to run a script on a VMWare VM using PowerCLI in which case you can use the invoke-vmscript command and set the scripttype to BAT

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40u1/html/Invoke-VMScript.html

The batch file would change the location. Alternatively you can use the copy-vmguestfile command and copy the batch file over and just use the invoke-vmscript command to run that batch file.

If the eventual goal is to have start up run the file then use the copy command and use the invoke command to update registry keys regarding startup.

https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FCopy-VMGuestFile.html